# NHibernate. SessionFactory.Delete deletes all tables

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I try to run example from https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started but after running next code all tables are cleared. I don't understand why it happens. I expecting that the store `var barginBasin = new Store { Name = "Bargin Basin" };` and rows from table `StoreProduct` with `Store_id` of this store will be deleted.

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    session.Delete(session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Store)).List<Store>()[0]);
    session.Flush();
}
```

`sessionFactory` initialization:

```
var dbConfig = OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
                      .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Oracle"))
                      .Driver<OracleDataClientDriver>()
                      .ShowSql();

                    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                      .Database(dbConfig)
                      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>())
                      .BuildSessionFactory();
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Oracle"
             connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=[IP])(PORT=[PORT]))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));PASSWORD=[PASSWORD];PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=[USER ID]"
             providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show your configuration for your session factory? It may be that your configuration is set to drop-create the tables each time its run.

Comment: Phill, edit the question